# Trying to evaluate high variance in large dataset

Tags: numerical-methods, standard-deviation, data-analysis

So I have an large active dataset, recording speed tests of connections. 
I am looking for the best approach to identify possible problem connections.

To do this I started by looking at averages etc. This works in a very simple scenario and is able to highlight problems in the moment, but I want to track high swings over time that indicate possible hardware issues etc.

I have tried using standard deviation, but I admit to being new to this.

Today I use the following:

1. Overall average speed
2. average of recent tests against overall average
3. Standard Deviation rating.

What I am looking to catch:

The problem connection are typically represented by peaks and valleys in the data where speeds are cutting in and out.

Is there a recommended approach?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I would plot a histogram of your speeds, first. If the data is roughly symmetric and normal, then mean and standard deviation are perfectly fine ways to characterize the center and spread of your distribution. If it's skewed to the right or left, then typically median and IQR are better measures of center and spread. The five-number summary is useful to calculate in any case.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I would be lying if I claimed to understand even half of the :). One issue I do have with __Standard Deviation__ is that between sites the connection speeds vary, with some being 10mbps and others 200mpbs. Is there any technique to normalize?